# css file not found in link(html)

Tags: html, css

> 404 error that the css file not found

Searched YouTube and can't find a solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>itays website </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" , class="home">Home</button>
    <button type="button" , class="contact">Contact</button>
    <button type="button" , class="services">Services</button>
    <button type="button" , class="about">About</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you create the file called "style.css" and have it in the same folder as this .html file?

Comment: @lucifer yea i checked that is the same name in the same folder

Comment: Please add your CSS code to the question. Commas are invalid between HTML attributes so remove them to start. How does your HTML render?

Comment: @lucifer my HTML file rendering perfectly

Comment: '.buttons home{
  background: #f9004d;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 13px 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: .4s;
}
buttons home:hover{
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #f9004d;
  cursor: pointer;
}'

Comment: What is the exact 404 error then? Is `style.css` mentioned in the error? I'm assuming it pops up in devtools?

Comment: @lucifer GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: What server are you using? VSCode live server? Some form of build tool?

Comment: @lucifer yoo bro it worked! ty very much

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @lucifer i used the other men that answered but it found the file but not apply the code in it

Answer (score 0):

Check that where did you creat your css file is it any folder

Check the file name properly

Comment: my html rendering perfect

Comment: Try to using src instead href

Comment: @Lucifer src won't actually work, it is supposed to be href. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: Can you share you code in codepen

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the css file and html file are in same folder